# Android AlarmManager wont call Broadcast Reciever

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

okay so ive tried everything i can find, its not working. Here is my code. Can someone tell me why it wont call the Receiver?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" />
...
```

AlarmReciever.java

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LogService.class);

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {

         LOGGER.debug("BroadcastReceiver, in onReceive:");

      }
}
```

DeviceMonitor.java

```
public class DeviceMonitor extends Service 
{
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startld) 
    {

        LOGGER.debug("alarmmanger settting from on start");

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent I = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, I, 0);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        LOGGER.debug("alarmmanger set from on start");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit more description could be useful for example do you get no logging message from your code, or it throws exception or ...

But I have a working code, which implements the same methods as you show at your question. Unfortunately you haven't posted all the relevant parts of the AndroidManifest.xml but I have this, maybe it will help.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="hu.fnf.devel.atlas.AtlasIncomingSMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This calls AtlasIncomingSMSReceiver class when a new SMS is received.

Comment: the onStart methods runs. it logs everything to the Log file, except the broadcast receiver onRecieve method.

Comment: When you define `<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">` you tell the app **which** Class to call, but you haven't told anything about **when**. You should make an <intent-filter> childnode (like above) and tell what to listen to. For example: `<intent-filter><action android:name="cica"></action></intent-filter>` After you defined **what** and **when** you can call this like: `Intent i = new Intent("cica"); sendBroadcast(i);` Of course you can use pre-defined events to listen to like: `<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >`

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to fix the problem by using the fully qualified path name i the xml document

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.realityi.measy.mdm.logs.AlarmReciever"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
</receiver>
```

and i was able to troubleshoot it using

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

which forced the sending of the boradcast

really hope this hopes someone. I'm new to Android development and this was killing me.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `AlarmReceiver` instead of `.AlarmReceiver` in the android mainfest file it will work.